# @ at start of filepath

Tags: java, ant, javac

What does an @ at the start of a filepath mean? As in:
`@/var/folders/d0/tq_0nszs1v5fbf2cqgqslddm0000gn/T/files8321409089632164183`

The context: 
  I was interested in extracting all the `javac` calls from an ant script. (It was the build script for [findbugs-1.3.9](http://findbugs.sourceforge.net/).) So I replaced the javac executable attribute with a script that echoed its arguments. The last argument was the above filepath. When I try to cat that file--either from the command line or within the script--I get a file-not-found.

Comment: Are you using filterset and filter? If that's the case you might be dealing with tokens. Look at this: http://ant.apache.org/manual/Types/filterset.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a way to pass a list of files to compile to `javac`:

> When executing javac, pass in the path and name of each argument file
>   with the '@' leading character. When javac encounters an argument
>   beginning with the character `@', it expands the contents of that file
>   into the argument list.

*From the [javac docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/tools/windows/javac.html#commandlineargfile).*